# C: Passing Arrays Through Abs Value Function

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a problem set for my first year c coding class and we are working on passing arrays through functions and I can't get mine to work. My theory is that I am passing something through the function incorrectly but I'm not 100% sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int absTable(int* x, int size)
{
    int i;
    double ans;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ans = fabs(x[i]);
        return(ans);
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    double x[50];
    int i;
    int n;
    double sum;
    double ans;

    printf("Enter less than 50 inputs and a chart will appear of your inputs absolute values \n");
    printf("How many inputs would you like? ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer: ");
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = absTable(x, n);
        printf("Interger: %.2f        Abs Value: %.2f \n", x[i], sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have an array of doubles double x[50]; but the function accepts an array of integers int absTable(int* x, int size)

Comment: Hint: You can only return *once* from a function. If you want to convert one array to another, you need to return an array. If you want to convert values in-place, you must modify them.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. There's a lot of small bugs in your application. You should learn to use a debugger, as most of those problems could be spotted using one.

The function needs to accept a `double*` as the array pointer. You probably have a warning about then when you compile. The function always return the absolute value of the first element, no matter how much elements you have in your array.

If I make a few assumption on the task you're trying to achieve, the correct program should be something lie that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double absTable(double* x, int index)
{
    return(fabs(x[index]));
}

int main(void)
{
    double x[50];
    int i;
    int n;
    double sum;
    // double ans; unused variable

    printf("Enter less than 50 inputs and a chart will appear of your inputs absolute values \n");
    printf("How many inputs would you like? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a floating-point value: ");
        scanf("%lf", &x[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = absTable(x, i);
        printf("FP Value: %.2f - ABS Value: %.2f \n", x[i], sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As a general advice, I was a bit confused about what the program should be doing. Your variable name `sum` implies that we should have the sum of something, but it contains an absolute value. Also, `x` would be better named `ArrayOfFPValues` or something like that. Don't forget that you're not writing code for the machine, but for other programmers.